# How to get diagonals from a coordinate in a 2D list?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, chess, diagonal

I want to make a Bishop.

Here's a quick catchup on what I have right now:

```
class Piece:
    def __init__(self, team, coord, name):
        self.naame = name
        self.value = 0
        self.team = team
        self.coord = coord
        legal_moves = []
        capture_moves = []


class Pawn(Piece):
    def __init__(self, team, coord):
        super().__init__(team, coord, name='Pawn')
        legal_moves = [[0, 1]]
        capture_moves = [[-1, 1], [1, 1]]
        self.value = 1


class Bishop(Piece):
    def __init__(self, team, coord):
        super().init(team, coord, name='Bishop')
        legal_moves = 


class Board():
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = [['x' for i in range(8)] for i in range(8)]

    def get_coord(self, x, y):
        return self.grid[x][y]
```

coordinates are basically `[['x' for i in range(8)] for i in range(8)]`, and legal moves are most easily explained in the example I gave for pawns. How do I do something like that for bishops? I was thinking a very long list comprehension, but I don't exactly know the syntax for it.

I don't know decorators very well, but I've been seeing something about `@property` and it seems interesting

Comment: Are the move spaces local coordinates or world?

Comment: @AgentBiscutt local coordinates, on a chess board. I'll edit that class in.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and a nested comprehension:

```
from itertools import product

moves = [(i*x, i*y) for x, y in product((-1, 1), repeat=2) for i in range(1, 8)]
# [(-1, -1), (-2, -2), (-3, -3), (-4, -4), (-5, -5), (-6, -6), (-7, -7), 
#  (-1, 1), (-2, 2), (-3, 3), (-4, 4), (-5, 5), (-6, 6), (-7, 7), 
#  (1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3), (4, -4), (5, -5), (6, -6), (7, -7),
#  (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7)]
```

Since you are calling this with `coord` available, you could be already restricting the moves here to stay within the bounds of the board:

```
x, y = coord = (3, 3)
legal_moves = [(dx, dy) for dx, dy in moves if 0 <= x+dx < 8 and 0 <= y+dy < 8]
# [(-1, -1), (-2, -2), (-3, -3), 
#  (-1, 1), (-2, 2), (-3, 3), 
#  (1, -1), (2, -2), (3, -3), 
#  (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: I don't know if coord is a python library, but `coord` is just a list of 2 numbers passed to a class or function

Comment: That was my assumption exactly, otherwise my code wouldn't work.

Comment: I have to change that 2nd code somehow because my grid is a class, and I don't know how that would work out. Is there a way to rewrite that in a way that I could pass limits into it? I'm gonna be honest my mind is drawing a blank on doing it like that.